# QML Drawer: cannot find any window to open popup in

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I'm using Qt5.9.1 . when i try to open drawer from another qml file i got error

> QML Drawer: cannot find any window to open popup in

I have my drawer in drawerBottom.qml and i want to open it from tablePage.qml using a qml function call. Here is my code....

**DrawerBottom.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.7 
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0 
import QtQuick.Layouts1.3 
import QtQuick.Window 2.3 
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2 
import Qt.labs.settings 1.0
Item {
    id: itemDrawerBottom
    Settings {
        id: settingBtm
        property string style: "Default"
    }
    Drawer{
        id: drawerBottom
        Flickable{
            width: 1338
            height: 142
            anchors.rightMargin: 8
            anchors.leftMargin: 13
            anchors.topMargin: 15
            anchors.bottomMargin: 0
            id: flickable
            clip: true
            anchors.fill: parent
            contentWidth: flickable.width ;
            contentHeight: flickable.height*1.2;
            Grid {
                id: gridBottom
                anchors.rightMargin: 9
                anchors.bottomMargin: 10
                anchors.fill: parent
                anchors.leftMargin: 21
                anchors.topMargin: 10
                columns: 2
                spacing: 20
                flow: Grid.LeftToRight
                Component{
                    id: componentDrawer
                    Button{
                        id:tBtnBottom1
                        implicitWidth: 130
                        implicitHeight: 35
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        ScrollIndicator.vertical: ScrollIndicator { }
    }
    function draweropen(){
        drawerbottom.open()
    } }
```

**and tablePage.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.3
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2
import Qt.labs.settings 1.0
Item {
    id: itemtable
    property Item itemDrawerBottom:DrawerBottom {}
    Button {
        id: button41
        x: 159
        y: 503
        width: 20
        height: 20
        onClicked:{
            itemDrawerBottom.draweropen()
        }
    }
}
```

**and i use an application window which is in mail.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.3
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2
import Qt.labs.settings 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    id:mainwindow
    visible: true
    width:Screen.width
    height: Screen.height
    title: qsTr("E-eatZ")
    GridLayout {
        id: gridLayouttableview
        x: 1048
        y: 168
        width: 529
        height: 592
        TablePage{

        }
        ColumnLayout {
            id: columnLayout1DrawerBottom
            x: -373
            y: 412
            width: 50
            height: 348
            DrawerBottom{

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello. Could you try do apply some consistent formatting to your code? An easy way to do this: Copy the code to QtCreator, select everything, press [CTRL] + [I]. Then you can press [TAB] to indent everything by 4 spaces, select everything again and copy it back to SO.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake.@derM.i have editted my code.please check it out and give me a solution.